# How to use a broken notebook's monitor?

Tags: laptop, display

I have a few year old Toshiba notebook, which is broken (hardware defect).

I still kept the monitor and was asking me if it is possible to connect it to a Desktop PC's graphic card?
Or is it possible to use the notebook graphic card in the desktop PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no to both questions.

You would need the electronics contained within an LCD's bevel to connect it to a normal PC. The panels themselves should be the same, but the electronics that they connect to are completely different. It's cheaper to get a new monitor than trying to convert this one.

As for the video card - no, you cannot use it in a desktop, they are completely different designs and there is no way to connect it to a desktop.

There is a decent market on eBay and the like for used, but working LCD panels and bevels though. You could probably make a quick buck on it.

Comment: Be sure to mark you ebay sale as "non working, for parts".  A quick search on ebay will give you a good idea of the value of the parts.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Usually those kind of displays are highly integrated with other laptop components. While newer LCD screens are somewhat standardized in sense that they all use LVDS signaling, you would need to find some graphic card that supports it. I do not know of that card. However, you could try to connect it to specialized computer (e.g. [Alix1c](http://www.pcengines.ch/pdf/alix1c.pdf) - page 17) which has such support.